# Setting ExpiresByType for entire server

Tags: apache

I run a server with several websites on it. I would like to implement default cache control behavior for all of these websites. Can I just do this by adding the following code to httpd.conf or must I make the changes in the configuration of each virtual host separately?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on

# Your document html
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 12 hours"

# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"

# Default
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What exact problem have you faced doing it this way?

Comment: I've not had any problems as I haven't tried it. I first wanted to ask whether this would work in theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation can be found in the [Apache HTTP Server web site](http://httpd.apache.org/). In the "Documentation" section on the left pane, click on your server version. [I'll assume 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/). Since you are looking for reference on specific directives, you can click on the [Directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/directives.html) link. You'll get an alphabetical index.

I won't copy the complete information, just a little sample for `ExpiresActive`. The important bit is the [top table](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresactive):

> ```
> Description: Enables generation of Expires headers
> Syntax:      ExpiresActive On|Off
> Default:     ExpiresActive Off
> Context:     server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
> Override:    Indexes
> Status:      Extension
> Module:      mod_expires
> ```

At "Context" we can read that the directive can be set at several places, including **server config**. So this answers your question: in theory, it should work. You should check the rest of the directives in order to make sure (or just test it).

Comment: Thanks for this ^ i had been applying the following inside the httpd-vhost.conf file in apache 2.4.6 and the following wasn't being applied. I then copied it into httpd.conf instead of my virtual host and it took affect.